# Why is function variable undefined when var comes after it?

Tags: javascript, var

I've read that a good practice is to put a var statement which defines all local variables at the top of each function. The following code shows why this is a good idea, since apparently a var *after* a variable is used makes it undefined.

**But can someone tell me *why* this is the case?**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                var a=1;
                function foo() {
                    //a = 2; //outputs 2,2 because this overwrites the external variable value
                    //var a = 2; //outputs 2,1 because the "var" keyword creates a second variable with local scope which doesn't affect the external variable 
                    console.log(a);
                    var a = 3; //ouputs "undefined,1" ???
                }
                foo();
                console.log(a);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function foo() {
  console.log(a);
  var a = 3;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
function foo() {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = 3;
}
```

because in JavaScript variable *declarations* are hoisted but *initializers* are not.

You can see that this is literally true with the following example:

```
e = 0;
function foo() {
  e = 1;
  try {
    throw 2;
  } catch (e) {
    var e = 3;
    alert("In catch " + e);
  }
  alert("Before end of function " + e);
}
foo();
alert("Outside function " + e);
```

which alerts

> In catch 3
>   Before end of function 1
>   Outside function 0

because the variable declaration is hoisted so the `e` outside the function is not changed by `e = 1`, but the `e = 3` occurs inside the `catch` so the `3` does not affect the `e` at the end of the function, instead over-writing the exception value.

Comment: Hoisting can be a pain sometimes.

Comment: that makes sense, another piece of JavaScript weirdness, thanks

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, the real pain comes from the half-baked hoisting.  `with ({ x: 4 }) { var x = 5; } return x`

Comment: @MikeSamuel—there is no such thing, what you have is `x` as an object property and as a local variable, they are completely different things. And "hoisting" is confusing jargon. Far better to explain that in javascript, declarations are processed before any code is executed.

Comment: @RobG, What you have is an assignment to a property that looks like part of a declaration.  That is why I called the hoisting "half-baked".

Comment: @MikeSamuel—and why I strongly dislike the term "hoisting", more accurate and easier to understand that declarations are processed before code is executed and assignments made. Jargon is suitable as shorthand only where it is understood by both parties, in many cases it obfuscates, as it does here.